# Specifically check for timeout error

Tags: go

I use the following to check for timeouts when calling a webservice, but I would like to check specifically if there is a timeout error returned. How do I do that :S

I have this:

```
// Timeout
type Timeout struct {
    Connect   time.Duration
    ReadWrite time.Duration
}

// TimeoutDialer
func TimeoutDialer(timeout *Timeout) func(net, addr string) (c net.Conn, err error) {
    return func(netw, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {    
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout(netw, addr, timeout.Connect)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeout.ReadWrite))
        return conn, nil
    }
}

// HttpClient
func HttpClient(config Config) *http.Client {
    to := &Timeout{
        Connect:   time.Duration(config.MaxWait) * time.Second,
        ReadWrite: time.Duration(config.MaxWait) * time.Second,
    }

    return &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: TimeoutDialer(to),
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention, you should turn off Keepalive in the Transport if you're going to set an absolute deadline on your connection. Otherwise you risk getting timeouts when reusing a connection.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you are specifically looking for i/o timeouts, you can use [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) to detect an `os.ErrDeadlineExceeded` error as documented in the [`net`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn) package:

```
// If the deadline is exceeded a call to Read or Write or to other
// I/O methods will return an error that wraps os.ErrDeadlineExceeded.
// This can be tested using errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded).
// The error's Timeout method will return true, but note that there
// are other possible errors for which the Timeout method will
// return true even if the deadline has not been exceeded.

if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) {
...
```

All possible timeouts will still conform to the `net.Error` with `Timeout()` set properly. All you need to check for is:

```
if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
```

Comment: Sorry, I should probably have been asserting a `net.Error`, since you could get Timeouts back that aren't an OpError.

Comment: So with http.Client.Timeout[go1.3+] it's impossible to check if error is timeout from Transport.CancelRequest? Is there a bug report for this? For me the message is totally confusing.

Answer (score 33):

You can simply pass an error to [os.IsTimeout()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsTimeout) and if it's a timeout returned by net/http then it will return true.

> `func IsTimeout(err error) bool`
>
> IsTimeout returns a boolean indicating whether the error is known to report that a timeout occurred.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - this is the simplest and most idiomatic way.

Comment: Although I appreciate the comment, "the most idiomatic way" is not and should never be accepted as a technical reason. Simple is better, however :)

Comment: A lot of people (including myself) learn Go (and other languages) by searching the internet, and they should be told the idiomatic way of doing something to learn the language more properly. A Go expert looking this up will immediately know which of the answers is the one he needs.

Comment: "Idiomatic Go" is nothing more than a style and it's incredibly dogmatic at that. In fact, often it's a language-agnostically poor practice. The correct way of doing something in programming is, most likely, entirely language agnostic. Use the right tool for the job, not what a bunch of purists tell you to do.

Comment: (I know this is an old discussion, but) Saying "'idiomatic' [...] should never be accepted as a technical reason' is equally dogmatic, and also objectively wrong.  In many cases, something is idiomatic because many (smart) people have come to the conclusion that it is a good way to do things.  Even if that is not the case, it will still make your code more understandable and maintainable for other programmers, *which is important*.  It certainly should not be the *only* criterion, but it should always be considered as *desirable*, unless there is a good reason otherwise.

Comment: I seem to remember my original point being: something being 'Idiomatic' should not be the *sole* reason. When someone states that something should be done solely because it is idiomatic, that person should also back up their argument with technical reasoning. I've found many times that developers like to throw the word and other principles around, but when questioned as to why it is valuable given this specific scenario, there exists a lack of thought beyond 'idiomatic' and 'what some people said on the internet'. Blindly accepting these things is common, and ineffective.

Comment: Make sure to also read the updated documentation: `This function predates errors.Is, and the notion of whether an error indicates a timeout can be ambiguous. For example, the Unix error EWOULDBLOCK sometimes indicates a timeout and sometimes does not. New code should use errors.Is with a value appropriate to the call returning the error, such as os.ErrDeadlineExceeded.`

Answer (score 15):

You want the `net.Error` interface. http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error

```
if e,ok := err.(net.Error); ok && e.Timeout() {
    // This was a timeout
} else if err != nil {
    // This was an error, but not a timeout
}
```

Note that the type assertion `err.(net.Error)` will correctly handle the `nil` case and return false for the `ok` value if `nil` is returned as the error, short-circuiting the `Timeout` check.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying `response, err := client.Do(req)
    if e, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && e.Timeout() {
     // This was a timeout
     fmt.Println("timeout")
        return
    }` gives me nothing :S

Comment: Are you sure it's a timeout error, then? you probably want to add a `else if err != nil` check to cover non-timeout errors.

Comment: I set the timeout (maxwait) to 2 seconds, and behind that a php script somewhere with a sleep of 10 seconds (thus this should be a timeout), the error returned is: Get http://api.vagrant/test.php: read tcp 192.168.33.10:80: i/o timeout

Comment: I'm not sure, `DialTimeout` should return a `net.Error` of some sort if it fails. I'm trying to read the source of the `net` package, but unfortunately low level networking code is system specific and thus a bit hard to find any proof of what is returned since it's buried under 30 function calls in different files.

Comment: Another way to check is to use os.IsTimeout() function. A working program can be find here - https://golangbyexample.com/net-http-timeout/

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible by doing something like this:

```golang
var timeoutError net.Error
if errors.As(err, &timeoutError); timeoutError.Timeout() {
    fmt.Println("timeout")
}
```