# How to `catch` specific errors

Tags: go, error-handling

For example, I am using one Go standard library function as:

```
func Dial(network, address string) (*Client, error)
```

This function may return errors, and I just care about errors which report "connection lost" or "connection refused", then do some code to fix these.
It seems like:

```
client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", ":1234")  
if err == KindOf(ConnectionRefused) {
  // do something
}
```

What's more, how to get all the errors a specific standard library function may return?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 https://tour.golang.org/methods/16

Comment: There is no direct / exact answer, partly blamed on the `net` package authors. Related / useful questions (about error handling): [Specifically check for timeout error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494950/specifically-check-for-timeout-error); and [Does go have standard Err variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177860/does-go-have-standard-err-variables/30178766#30178766); and [Go. Best practice to handle error from multiple abstract level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346694/go-best-practice-to-handle-error-from-multiple-abstract-level/37347531#37347531).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In modern Go, the best *general* way to do this is with the [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) and [`errors.As`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As) functions in the standard library.

For the example in the original question, this is quite straight forward:

```golang
if errors.Is(err, syscall.ECONNREFUSED) {
    // Connection refused error
} else {
    // Some other kind of error
}
```

However, this only works for errors which are properly wrapped/created to use these capabilities.  Sometimes you may need to mix-and-match the use of `errors.Is` and `errors.As` with string comparison. I've made [a video](https://youtu.be/UjMnAXIVWJg) that goes into some of these details for those interested.

---

My old answer:

There's no standard way to do this.

The most obvious way, which should only be used if no other method is available, is to compare the error string against what you expect:

```
if err.Error() == "connection lost" { ... }
```

Or perhaps more robust in some situations:

```
if strings.HasSuffix(err.Error(), ": connection lost") { ... }
```

But many libraries will return specific error types, which makes this much easier.

In your case, what's relevant are the various error types exported by the [`net`](https://golang.org/pkg/net) package: [AddrError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#AddrError), [DNSConfigError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DNSConfigError), [DNSError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DNSError), [Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error), etc.

You probably care most about [net.Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error), which is used for network errors.  So you could check thusly:

```
if _, ok := err.(net.Error); ok {
    // You know it's a net.Error instance
    if err.Error() == "connection lost" { ... }
}
```

> What's more, how to get all the errors a specific standard library function may return?

The only fool-proof way to do this is to read the source for the library. Before going to that extreme, a first step is simply to read the godoc, as in the case of the `net` package, the errors are pretty well documented.

Comment: what is this err.(net.Error) syntax?

Comment: @JBaczuk: That's a [type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38816843/13860). If the error's underlying type is `net.Error`, `ok` will evaluate as true.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the [`errors.Is()`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) function to compare some standard errors:

```
client, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":1234")
if errors.Is(err, net.ErrClosed) {
    fmt.Println("connection has been closed.")
}
```

A common file opening scenario:

```
file, err := os.Open("non-existing");
if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist) {
        fmt.Println("file does not exist")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
You can also use [`errors.As()`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As) if you'd like to check the error type:

```
client, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":1234")
var errC = net.ErrClosed
if errors.As(err, &errC) {
    fmt.Printf("connection has been closed: %s", errC)
}
client.Close()
```

A more detailed explanation can be found in the [Go Blog](https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors).