# Can TCP clients receive data after a read timeout?

Tags: go, tcp

I create a tcp connection pool in golang and set every connection to keep alive, when I get a connection from pool, I will set a 10 seconds timeout by SetDeadline function. Now I want to know, if a timeout error occur after reading from a connection and server send message to me after this point, will the message be put into my connection receive buffer? Will I get the message in next reading? If so, how should I handle the timeout error? Close the connection and create a new one?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494950/specifically-check-for-timeout-error

Comment: If you've read a complete message, then there was no timeout error. If you encountered a timeout error, it's up to the logic of your program how you want to handle that.

Comment: @JimB I know how to check a timeout error, but I don’t know if a timeout error occur and after that server send a message to me by the connection, will I get the message by reading from the connection

Comment: The error is returned from a Read operation -- if you didn't receive the data and got an error, then you didn't receive the data. If you received the data, then you received the data. What is the point of the timeout if you want to see if the server sent the message after the timeout? Why not check if the server sent the message after you checked after the timeout, and so on? Set the timeout appropriately first, and if you didn't get message, timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a timeout error occur after reading from a connection and server send message to me after this point, will the message be put into my connection receive buffer?

If you don't close the connection, yes.

> Will I get the message in next reading?

Yes, if you reset the deadline. Although this does beg the question why you set a timeout in the first place.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3001")
    check(err)

    go slowServer(l)

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3001")
    check(err)
    conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))

    b := make([]byte, 512)

    n, err := conn.Read(b)
    fmt.Printf("%q, %v\n", b[:n], err) // "", i/o timeout

    // Reset deadline
    conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))

    n, err = conn.Read(b)
    fmt.Printf("%q, %v\n", b[:n], err) // "hello world", <nil>
}

func slowServer(l net.Listener) {
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    check(err)

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    io.WriteString(conn, "hello world")
    conn.Close()
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// "", read tcp 127.0.0.1:50488->127.0.0.1:3001: i/o timeout
// "hello world", <nil>
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Id60hHK7tKF

Comment: thank you，i think I understand. If I use keep alive connection, I should check response valid in programming logic rather than rely on underlay of tcp connection, right?

Comment: You always (always!) have to check data received over the network in any case.

Comment: In my mind, I have two choice to handle this problem, 1. close the connection and create new one, resend request message to server by new connection 2.add sequence number to request and response message, check response sequence number is pair to request. I only have little programming practice, so which one is better?

Comment: @wangjun, we cannot tell you how to handle your errors. That depends entirely on the application. You have to figure it out yourself.